# What is a good way to shift a function by 90 degrees through hardware?

Tags: fourier

I want to shift a function by 90.

Comment: Analog or in DSP or in an FPGA?

Comment: FPGA but a fast one.

Comment: Then add that to the question, maybe give some more information about the signal, what you have to work with, and why you need the 90 rotation.

Comment: Number of bits and frequency of the signal, please.

Answer (score 2):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform  shows that sin transforms to -cos, so yes -- you take the negative of the Hilbert transform to transform sin to cos (seems like a long way to go to do what you're trying to do)